# init: logstash main process (19281) terminated with status 1

Tags: amazon-ec2, elasticsearch, logstash

I run Amazon Linux instance with logstash 6.4.0.

```
[root@****** dragan]# cat /etc/issue
Amazon Linux AMI release 2017.03
```

I wanted to upgrade logstash so I uninstalled 6.4.0 and tried to install 7.3.2. I got an error so I decided to role back and then installed again old version 6.4.0. Since then the service is going up and down...

Here is the output from messages. Logging to /var/log/logstash stopped so this is all I have.

```
Oct 16 13:01:17 localhost init: logstash main process ended, respawning
Oct 16 13:01:28 localhost init: logstash main process (19281) terminated with status 1
Oct 16 13:01:28 localhost init: logstash main process ended, respawning
Oct 16 13:01:39 localhost init: logstash main process (19425) terminated with status 1
Oct 16 13:01:39 localhost init: logstash main process ended, respawning
Oct 16 13:01:50 localhost init: logstash main process (19540) terminated with status 1
Oct 16 13:01:50 localhost init: logstash main process ended, respawning
Oct 16 13:02:00 localhost init: logstash main process (19647) terminated with status 1
Oct 16 13:02:00 localhost init: logstash main process ended, respawning
Oct 16 13:02:11 localhost init: logstash main process (19783) terminated with status 1
Oct 16 13:02:11 localhost init: logstash main process ended, respawning
Oct 16 13:02:23 localhost init: logstash main process (20114) terminated with status 1
Oct 16 13:02:23 localhost init: logstash main process ended, respawning
Oct 16 13:02:35 localhost init: logstash main process (29477) terminated with status 1
Oct 16 13:02:35 localhost init: logstash main process ended, respawning
Oct 16 13:02:47 localhost init: logstash main process (6451) terminated with status 1
Oct 16 13:02:47 localhost init: logstash main process ended, respawning
Oct 16 13:02:59 localhost init: logstash main process (15826) terminated with status 1
Oct 16 13:02:59 localhost init: logstash main process ended, respawning
```

Any idea what happened and how to fix it?

Cheers,
Dragan